# always encrypted query within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, always-encrypted

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a column that is encrypted using the "Always Encrypted" feature.  In SSMS, I've specified the "column encryption setting=enabled" connection option and the "Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted" setting is also enabled.

This query, executed by itself, works as expected.

```
DECLARE @value varchar(25) = '345'

SELECT PrivateID
FROM TestDB.dbo.tblData
WHERE PrivateID = @value
```

But, if I try to put this in a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value varchar(25) = '345'

    SELECT PrivateID
    FROM TestDB.dbo.tblData
    WHERE PrivateID = @value
END
GO
```

I get errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal error. Metadata for parameter '@p850913a51d1247f290af5a8e7dd24f25' in statement or procedure 'ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Test
>       AS
>       BEGIN
>           DECLARE @value AS VARCHAR (25) = @p850913a51d1247f290af5a8e7dd24f25;
>           SELECT PrivateID
>           FROM   TestDB.dbo.tblData
>           WHERE  PrivateID = @value;
>       END' is missing in resultset returned by sp_describe_parameter_encryption.

What is the correct way to get results from an always encrypted column using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of this error courtesy of an MSDN forum post "[always encrypted query within stored procedure](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e48eceee-2bf2-43c9-b690-eadd91330705/always-encrypted-query-within-stored-procedure)".

When trying to create (or alter) the stored procedure with parameterization enabled in SSMS, this is what a trace shows was being submitted to the server before I would see the error in the original post (reference [sp_describe_parameter_encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-parameter-encryption-transact-sql)).

```
exec sp_describe_parameter_encryption N'ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value AS VARCHAR (25) = @p9f7f4f9078e14e1e8b661791c0c1348a;
    SELECT PrivateID
    FROM   TestDB.dbo.tblData
    WHERE  PrivateID = @value;
END

',N'@p9f7f4f9078e14e1e8b661791c0c1348a varchar(25)'
```

To accomplish what I was trying to test, I just needed to create the simple stored procedure below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Test
    @PrivateID varchar(25) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT PrivateID
    FROM TestDB.dbo.tblData
    WHERE PrivateID = @PrivateID
END
```

And then with the parameterization settings enabled in SSMS, execute it as follows.

```
DECLARE @t varchar(25) = '345'
EXEC dbo.Test @t
```